# Is there any way to assign a csv file from dbfs (databricks) path to a variable in pyspark?

Tags: python, databricks

I am executing following code in Databricks to convert a 
spark dataframe into csv dataframe.csv and store in dbfs path.

```
df.coalesce(1)\
 .write\
 .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
 .option("header", "true")\
 .save("dataframe.csv")
```

This file is getting created in *dbfs:/dataframe.csv*.
I need to assign this file to a filename so that I can attach the file to mail. I am using :

`filename = pandas.read_csv("dataframe.csv")`

But this is throwing me error: 
`IOError: File dataframe.csv does not exist`

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepend the filename with the `/dbfs` folder, like this:

```
filename = "/dbfs/somefile.csv"
frame = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

Here, you’ll be using Databricks file system’s [local file API](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#local-file-apis), which is one of several ways that you can interact with this distributed file system.

Comment: I believe filename has to be like this "dbfs:/dataframe.csv"

Comment: @HussainBohra That's the way you would do it when you're using the Spark connectors, yes. However, Databricks provides a local file API, which makes the file system appear mounted on your workspace, so you can use it seemingly like any other file system. You'd then use `/dbfs/somefile.csv`. If you don't believe me, test it out ;-)